# Why is the number of neurons used in various neural networks power of 2?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, ai-design, hyper-parameters

I have noticed that almost all tutorials take the number of neurons as a power of 2. Is there any proper mathematical and well-proven reason for that?

If you sometimes change it to some other odd value, then we get a very long and weird error calling about a dozen things making the traceback of a page. Is there any reason for that?

> I had tried it on a text predicting RNN with some GRU and LSTM layers mixed (bidirectional). I changed the no. of neuron units and It also resulted in an error. So, any ideas/theories?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! You say "If you sometimes change it to some other odd value, then we get a very long and weird error calling about a dozen things making the traceback of a page", but I don't think this is caused by the fact that the number of neurons is not a power of 2. So, can you provide a concrete example where that occurs? Also, note that, for each layer, you may have a different number of neurons.

Comment: @nbro, No I do not have a concrete example. I have just migrated to another OS so most of my code is lost. But even then in most tutorials the no. is always a power of 2. So I was wondering what reason was there behind it.....